# Behavior driven development and SpecFlow

Tags: bdd, specflow

I haven't any real experience in BDD and I've recently discovered [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/home.aspx). I've read a bit about it (and [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/wiki)), I went through some [screen casts](http://www.specflow.org/getdoc/7a17d618-cb24-40e4-904b-b335c34c98d8/screencast.aspx), and I must say that I'm moderatly convinced. Of course, by nature, the examples provided as an introduction are relatively simple. Is anybody using SpecFlow on real (read "complex") projects and finding that tool helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gojko Adzic has written a whole book (www.specificationbyexample.com) where he interviewed various teams around the globe working according to these concepts for several years. The book not only describes there experience but also summarizes very well common challenges and benefits teams reported. I think this book can help convincing management as well as provides some guidance when starting with this. It is not a step-by-step cook book, though, neither does it talk in detail about specific tools (which is not necessary IMHO).

To talk about first hand experience, we (TechTalk) are using SpecFlow since several years in projects of different size, domains and architecture. We are doing mainly custom development in various domains (financial sector, government, GIS) and our projects are usually having a 2-9 months duration with a size of 150-500 PD. The largest projects we do with SpecFlow are 1800+ PD - these are long running programs for several years with ongoing frequent releases.

We are also using SpecFlow in product development, e.g. in SpecLog (www.speclog.net).

We are also coaching larger projects in ATDD and Specification-By-Example in various industries (automotive, financial services, ...) who are applying these concepts quite successfully. These projects are partly also on other platforms, e.g. on Java we used JBehave so far, although if I would start a project right now I would strongly consider Cucumber-JVM.

I also recommend checking out the (free) screen casts at skillsmatter.com who are running related conferences since several years (BDDX, CukeUp). These always have some experience reports from various domains and industries.

Comment: I can only agree with @chr99ha - it works! I've been using BDD at several customer in different businesses and teams of different maturity. But please note that the tooling is not the thing; talking to each other is! I wrote more about this here; http://www.marcusoft.net/2012/06/what-bdd-is-all-about.html